# Multiplas instâncias de Django numa só máquina

Tags: django, aplicação-web, nginx

Tenho um projeto em Django que funciona como uma aplicação web para uso em empresas.
A empresa tem 4 filiais, e temos um servidor disponível.
O objetivo é replicar o projeto 4x na mesma máquina, cada um com uma base de dados isolada. Cada filial apenas acede a uma instância, mas todas têm de estar disponíveis simultaneamente, e na mesma máquina.
Estou a utilizar NGINX para servir as aplicações.
 Neste momento, tenho vários blocos "server" apontados a portas diferentes a funcionar como reverse proxy de várias aplicações Django a executar no terminal.
Copiei a pasta do projeto para 4 pastas diferentes dentro de /var/www e mudei o nome da base de dados para isolar os utilizadores e os dados de cada uma.
Neste momento, por exemplo:
A filial 1 acede a: http://dominio:80/

A filial 2 acede a: http://dominio:90/; ...
Existe alguma solução mais eficiente ou correta para disponibilizar a aplicação? Poderá ocorrer race conditions a aceder à base de dados ou algum tipo de problema ao correr várias instâncias do Django na mesma máquina?

Answer (score 0):

o que vc está fazendo é aceitável.

Se as 4 filiais, vão usar sempre o mesmo sistema, vc poderia manter 1 código somente no deploy e usar vários settings ?

As suas strings do gunicorn poderiam apontar para settings diferentes ...
isso vai facilitar o deploy de atualizações.

Outra coisa que poderia , mas ainda deveria ser discutível, seria usar o django sites. QUe foi feito para ter várias "filiais" usando o mesmo projeto Django. Mas provvelmente vc teria que alterar o código da sua aplicação ...   de uma estudada e talvez **fique pra versão 2.0**

Nao precisa utilizar a mesma base de dados, DESDE que vc colocasse as diferentes bases na mesma instaâcnia de Banco de dados (espero que esteja usando postgresql)
facilitaria ter relatórios EXTRA filiaais.
Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte